# Windows Installer: Specifying the install order of prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer, prerequisites

I am using the Windows installer that comes with VS2010. This app uses .Net4 and will mainly run on xp machines. It also uses some third party assemblies that require .Net2.

If the pc is using XP SP2 I also need to install Windows Imagining Components.

Selecting .Net2 in the prerequsites will not install WIC and will try to install .Net2 on Windows 7 which casues an error.

If I check the .Net3 SP1 prerequisite this will include .Net2 and WIC. Unfortunately when the installer runs it first tries to install framework 4 before framework 3.5.

Is there a way of changing the order of the prerequisites so that 3.5 is installed before 4?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the method to add WIC to your prerequisites list.](http://wizzard0.livejournal.com/213674.html)

Quoted from above link:

"create a custom MSI Bootstrapper Package for WIC -and- add it as a dependency for the standard .NET bootstrapper package

I've created the bootstrapper and patch for the standard .NET bootstrapper which comes with VS.

Download [this self-extracting archive](http://tvori.info/redist/wic_bootstrapper_patch.exe) , unpack to %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages, and you're ready to go.

If everything is OK, you should see "Windows Imaging Component" in ClickOnce Prerequisites window. Add it to your project, and it should install fine from now on"

This may solve your problem, because if you select it in the list it will be installed before .Net 4 and there is no need to install .Net 2 beforehand.